# Oracle Forms: Cant reference item name with an array

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am learning to work with Oracle Forms and got a problem within the pl/sql editor.

I have many checkboxes on a canvas and with a "when-button-pressed"-trigger I want to check which check boxes are "checked".

At first I declared a varray with the names of the check boxes - for example ('box_1','box_2',...).

Now I am trying the following syntax and it doesnt work:

```
for i in 1..example_array.count loop
    if checkbox_checked(:example_block.array1(i)) then 
        .....;
```

It says: Error 49 at line ..., column ... - bad bind variable 'example_block.array1('

But when I use the name of the check box it works:

```
for i in 1..example_array.count loop
    if checkbox_checked(:example_block.box_1) then 
        .....;
```

I cant reference the array or I am using the wrong syntax for it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Name_In` function, along with which belongs to ***Forms*** not exists as a predefined routine for neither *PL/SQL* nor *SQL*, in order to represent the value of an item such as

```
for i in 1..example_array.count 
loop
  if checkbox_checked(Name_In('example_block.box_'||i)) then ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. It says: Error 222 at line ..., column ... no function with name 'COPY' exists in this scope. Do I need to install the "copy" function?

Comment: currently I ain't have oracleforms installed and so cannot able to reproduce. Copy is an internal function, which does not need to be installed, and is used for assignment, perhaps that yields the error. Can you retry through use of `checkbox_checked(Name_In('example_block.box_'||i))` by directly use of `Name_In` function... @IronMan3000

Comment: Thank you for the tips with Name_In and Copy.
Name_In returns the value of the check box when checked so i solved it this way and it works for now:
...
v_cdummy := to_char('example_block.'||example_array(i));
...
if checkbox_checked(v_cdummy) then 
...

Comment: nice news, I've just removed the part related to `Copy` function which could be used for a later time @IronMan3000